# Echo just the value of database row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a little trouble getting just the value from a database row. I have a page with a working database connection. What I want is to just echo the value from a specific row using something like `<?php echo $value;?>` where `$value` is the following code:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM assortiment WHERE Id = 11481";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    echo $row["Fotomateriaal"];
                }
            } else {
                echo "No results";
            }
```

Why? Because using this piece of code outputs: `72157634651630294`. Which is the value I'm trying to get. BUT I would like to use it in a form like `<?php echo value;?>` because I'm trying to use it in this piece of code:

```
echo do_shortcode( '[slickr-flickr id="21@XXX" search="sets" set="' . $value . '" size="large" items="19" bottom="30" responsive="on" orientation="landscape" restrict="orientation" type="galleria" galleria_options="lightbox:true;thumbnail:lazy"]');
```

I tried:

```
do_shortcode( '[slickr-flickr id="21@XXX" search="sets" set="' . $sql . '" size="large" items="19" bottom="30" responsive="on" orientation="landscape" restrict="orientation" type="galleria" galleria_options="lightbox:true;thumbnail:lazy"]');
```

But that just echo's the code and not the value. Would something like this work? This code doesn't work...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM assortiment WHERE Id = 11481";
echo $row["Fotomateriaal"];
```

I hope I made it clear what I'm trying to do. It's a bit hard to explain on here...

Comment: echo will not display a full row , it is to echo single items.. you will have to use var_dump / print_r

Comment: Just assign it to a variable instead of echoing it? `echo $row["Fotomateriaal"];` ==> `$value = $row["Fotomateriaal"];` (although if you're just expecting a single result, you don't need to loop over it with `while`)

Comment: just do `$value = $row["Fotomateriaal"];` instead of `echo $row["Fotomateriaal"];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the result of the query in a variable and use later in your code

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $value = $row["Fotomateriaal"];
    }
} else {
    $value = "No results";
}
```

Now in `$value` you have the record returned by your query. I assume only one row is returned. Your latest example is not working because you are not executing the query nor you are fetching any data.

Comment: Wow, that was it.. thanks! I had to add the `$sql = "SELECT * FROM assortiment WHERE Id = 11481"; $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);` But it works! Thanks a million.